# Upgrade from TokenCache built using ADAL v2.x to ADAL v3.x

Tags: adal

We have a custom implementation of TokenCache for persistent storage . I'm trying to bring legacy dependencies up to date (ADAL 2.x -> ADAL 3.17.0 (latest)). I hit a roadblock because the TokenCache Deserialize method, looks at the version of the serialized cache and refuses to deserialize it, because it is 2, and the latest version expects 3.

Is there any way I can manually upgrade the serialized AuthenticationResult classes from V2 to to the new AuthenticationResultEx class in V3? i dont mind hacky code since this will be a one time thing.

Do you have any other suggested ways to migrate from V2 token cache to V3? Is there any way i can use the refresh token or something to populate the V3 token cache?

Answer (score 0):

Brijesh, the cache structure from v2 and v3 are not forward compatible, so there is not a 'supported' way to do this migration.

A *hacky* code for this is to download the source code from [adal v2 and v3](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/releases) and then use the classes for both library versions to convert the deserialized cache, however this will give you some work.